# Не могу распарсить JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Хочу распарсить Json от Yandex Geocoder для получения адреса по координатам, но не могу. Что я делаю не так?

```
public void OnClick(View view) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    response SourceJs = gson.fromJson(source,response.class);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) SourceJs[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
class response {
    List<GeoObjectCollection>  GeoObjectCollection;
}

class GeoObjectCollection {
    List<featureMember> featureMember;
}

class  featureMember {
    List<GeoObject> GeoObject;
}

class  GeoObject {
    String name;
}
```

[Сам Json](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=2c9d1bb0-93c8-4e53-8791-c671ef4c1bcd&geocode=37.597576,55.771899&format=json)

Answer (score 1):

Я посмотрел ваш json ответ от сервера, там только один элемент response передается, зачем вы пытаетесь считать результат в массив Result[]? Считывать нужно Result, а не Result[].
И еще, приложите описание класса Result, возможно в нем есть ошибка.

Comment: Я внес поправки в код. Там не Result[] , a response

Comment: @МеркурийМлечный все должно распарситься, если нет, то нужно смотреть ваш класс response, скорее всего он описан некорректно. Посмотрите [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/gson.php) пример работы с библиотекой gson.